# How to make a percentage of an image transparent using just HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to implement a barometer using HTML/CSS only. I have a background image which is just borders. And a foreground image filled with color on top of it. The idea is I want to display x% colour of the foreground image to show a progress of x%. I thought that maybe making a (1-x)% part of the image transparent would do the trick. Is there a way to implement this barometer using a background and foreground image ?

HTML:-

```
<div class="alignfullhigher">
<table> 
<tbody> 
<tr>
<td class="backtable"><img src="background_no_fill_only_outline.png" width="100%"></td> 
</tr>
<tr> 
<td class="fronttable"><img src="foreground_fill.png" width="100%" height="160px"></td> 
</tr> 
</tbody>    
</table> 
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
.alignfullhigher{position:relative; width:100%; height:160px;top:0;right:0;}
.backtable{position:absolute;z-index:-1; width:100%; height:auto;}
.fronttable{position:relative;width:100%; clip: rect(0px,100px,160px,0px); )}
```

Comment: have you tried playing with css transitions and opacity?

Comment: use linear-gradient where you can set a solid and transparent color over the image

Comment: thanks but can i implement opacity or transparent colour for say x% width of the image? sorry i am new to html/css

Comment: show us some code and we will show you how ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif the HTML and CSS respectively :)

Comment: edit your question and put it there ;)

Comment: the background and foreground completely superimpose. So if i make (1-x) part of the foreground image transparent it should do the job. (I guess)

Comment: You are on the right track with the table. Ive done this sort of thing before. you need to split the image into segments, have several images in a cell using relative positioning, and also set a default image behind all the others.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy if you use background images for the graphics.
Using these two images:

[image]
[image]

You can just put them on top of each other, the "full" one in a smaller rectangle than the "empty" one.

```css
div {
  width: 49px; height: 184px;
  background-size: 49px 184px;
  background-position: left bottom;
}

.empty {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4KVi.png);
  position: relative;
}

.full {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Cf3.png);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 60%; /* vary this number to change the barometer */
}
```

```html
<div class="empty">
  <div class="full"></div>
</div>
```